# Put column values into single cell with comma delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider a table in SQL Server has a column `Item`, I tried to created a query to covert all values in the column into a single cell result into comma separated string, for example:

Table:

```
| Item |
--------
| milk |
| sugar|
| salt |
| .... |
```

Query result:

```
|       Item List         |
---------------------------
| milk, sugar, salt ..... |
```

It would be better to have some customization as

```
|                    Item List                     |
----------------------------------------------------
| milk as milk, sugar as sugar, salt as salt ..... |
```

I saw there is option as `unpivot` however it has to be definitive amount of values in the column. Just wondering any available functions to support this goal if target column value is dynamic

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv).  Your desire for customization is referenced by it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Consider you want to populate:

```
declare @csv nvarchar(max);
```

If you have sql server 2016 or earlier:

```
set @csv = 
    stuff((
        select  ',' + item + ' as ' + item
        from    @data
        for     xml path('')
    ),1,1,'');
```

If you have sql server 2017 or later:

```
set @csv = (
    select  string_agg (item + ' as ' + item, ',')
    from    @data
);
```

Comment: @DaleK. You're right.  I'll look up a good dupe and vote to close.

Comment: And if you are going to show `for xml` at least do it properly: `', ' + ` OP wants an extra space. `for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,len(', '),'')` to prevent XML escaping